# Unable to setup Maven in windows 7

Tags: java, maven

I have installed JDk 8 and even dowloaded apache maven 3.3.3.Also I have set path for both Java and Maven but when I tried executing mvn --version command in command prompt then it is showing an error that "'mvn' is not recognized as internal or external command operable program or batch file"

Comment: What about running it with the absolute path?  If you had the Command window open before you set the PATH then the window may not have the updated PATH.  Open a new `cmd` and try again.

Comment: Have you restarted command prompt since you added the paths to your PATH environment variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the below steps in order to setup Maven on windows machine.

Please make sure to change your maven downloaded version. Hope you extracted in below location or you can do in any location and make sure to give correct path.

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.3.3
```

Then you need to set `M2_HOME, M2, MAVEN_OPTS` to environment variables.

```
M2_HOME=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.3.3

M2=%M2_HOME%\bin

MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx512m
```

Done !!

Simply open new command prompt and check `mvn -version`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running on Windows, just define your M2_HOME variable to point to your maven installation folder and add %M2_HOME%\bin to your PATH variable.

This is a pretty decent tutorial: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/what-is-maven-and-how-do-i-install-it.html

Comment: Simply follow: http://maven.apache.org/install.html Just put bin folder of the distribution into Path that's it...nothing more...

Comment: Some IDEs care about M2_HOME to pick that particular Maven instance

Comment: I tried the same which has been given like in tutorials which you have provided here in the link but even I am getting same issue

Comment: @BawgeChandu After you add them close the terminal and open it again.

Answer (score 0):

If you've followed the official installation instruction and it works when you specify `mvn.bat`, but not `mvn` then your `PATHEXT` environment variable needs to be adjusted:

```
set PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD
```

The command above is usually the default.

Answer (score 0):

**Steps to set-up Maven**

1. Make sure JDK is installed, and `JAVA_HOME` variable is added as Windows environment variable.
2. Download the [Maven zip file](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi), for example : apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.zip. Unzip it to the folder where you want.

Assume you unzip to this folder – `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9`

[image]

> That’s all, just folders and files, installation is NOT required.

3. Add both `M2_HOME` and `MAVEN_HOME` variables in the Windows environment, and point it to your Maven folder.

[image]

4. Edit `PATH` variable, append Maven bin folder – `%M2_HOME%\bin`, so that you can run the Maven’s command everywhere.

[image]

5. Run `mvn –version` in the command prompt, if the below message is displayed the maven setup is done.
   [image]

ENJOY CODING!!!